# How I can run code when an app have been killed on iPhone?

Tags: ios

I need opportunity, run some code at the moment when my app is killed. For example, a user doesn't open my app in the course of week or month.

Some information about working my app.
The User can save settings which contain push notification. These local push notification my app can get every day, but time every day can be different and I want to create local push when my app is closed and doesn't open during some days, weeks or months etc.

I have read about "silent push notification", but it is not fit me because in my app hasn't a server. Also, I have read about "significant location", also it is not fit me. Who knows an alternative way, how its implementation?

Comment: Your app was just killed. What code would you need to run? Why not do what you need when the app goes into the background?

Comment: you need to restart your app, or implement an _extension_ (e.g. today) which will be executed by iOS time after time in the background so you may have a chance to run some lightweight code time after time, but such idea may be out of context if your app doesn't need any _extension_ in the first place, because of its nature.

Comment: @rmaddy no, a user doesn't open my app in the course of some days for example. The User can save settings which contain push notification. These local push notification my app can get every day, but time every day can be different and I want to create local push when my app is closed and doesn't open during some days, weeks or months etc.

Comment: If your app is terminated you can't run code. only way to wake it might be some background modes or remote notifications, otherwise the user must open the app. thats it as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

Since your goal is to run a local notification some number of days after the app is terminated, one solution is to schedule a local notification when the app enters the background. When the app enters the foreground or if it is restarted, check if enough time has passed or not. If not, delete the most recently scheduled local notification. This way it only triggers if the user doesn't actually use your app for those days (or whatever timeframe your choose).

Comment: I think this is the most suitable solution for this case.

Comment: Maybe I explain badly, but I will try again) A user can save settings which contain local push notifications. The user wants these local pushes to arrive every day. I want to create local push notification on one day, for example on this today. After it every day create new local push notification, but I am worried about the situation when a user won't open my app, and I won't can to create local push notification and the user won't get a local push notification.

Comment: You need to schedule the local notifications before your app is killed. If you want it to appear every day, create a repeating notification.

Comment: @rmaddy Okay. I understand I can create a local notification on one day before my app is killed. But if I want to create a repeating notification, this notification will be arriving every day at the same time. But time in my local notification can shift every day. For example, you can see prayer time, there you can see how often time changing every day.  https://www.islamicfinder.org/world/ukraine/702550/lviv-prayer-times/

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to use repeating notifications if the scheduled time is variable. There is also definitely no way to run some code in the background if app is killed, so the only suitable solution would be to use remote push notifications. If you don't want to deal with the trouble of making a push server etc. Firebase might be a good choice: [Firebase Cloud Messaging client app on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)

Comment: I'm going to look at it, thanks. But I don't believe it help me, because these times calculation with help user coordinate.

Comment: @YuraPetrov great that you found at least a hint, however if you more clearly specify what you mean by saying: "these times calculation with help user coordinate" I might suggest another workaround as well ;))

Comment: A user gets prayers times every day.
This time calculation with help user coordinate.
For example, you can see on this site how time changing, and this times for one location. But a user can move on the world, and his location will change. 
https://www.islamicfinder.org/world/ukraine/702550/lviv-prayer-times/